# Finding patterns of volume worked - Productivity Mix Correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, k-means, change-point

I am trying to generate labor standards (the amount of productivity per hour an employee should be accomplishing) based off of historical data volumes. I do not have the start and end time that a specific task was completed or started. I do however have various dimensions related to these tasks. An example would be for collections I know if the account was a high dollar, low dollar, mid dollar account. I know the time stamp that is associated with the completion of the entry (not the start time however). I also know the employee that worked the account. So I can see volume by hour by employee, but what I can’t determine is how much time they spent on a certain account type versus others.

I would like to determine a way to apply some sort of regression analysis or other technique to account for mixes in items worked and determine the number of accounts that should be worked per hour based on a typical run rate given the different account type fields (high dollar and financial class namely).

I realize this is a very broad question but I’m hoping someone can walk me through a statistical model or technique I could use to help me achieve this. I believe the toughest aspect to account for is the mix in volume per hour. For example, in the below table it is not possible for me to merely take an average of accounts worked per hour of each account type (High, Mid, Low, etc) because each employee would be working different types of accounts each hour. So I'm not able to definitively say that a High dollar account for financial class 8 can have 4 accounts completed per hour because of this mix.

| Total per hour | High Dollar | Mid dollar | Low dollar | Ultra low dollar | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 11 |
| Employee 2 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 10 |
| Employee 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 12 | 14 |
| Employee 4 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 0 | 12 |
| Employee 5 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 8 |

I am posting an example raw dataset below. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need further clarification I'm happy to provide it. I recently obtained my masters in data science and this will be my first "real life" stats project, so I'm hoping I can deliver!

Thank you all!

I have used box and whisker plots to identify outliers, but I'm not sure how to account for mixes in account types without using some sort of regression analysis or technique to determine relationships and mixes better. But I'm really struggling getting started.

| Employee_ID | FinClass | Liability Level | Work_Units | Work_Activity_Case_ID | Work Activity Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | H | 1 | 4750591-89044 | 4/11/2023 18:56 |
| 3 | 12 | H | 1 | 6901244-16522 | 4/11/2023 18:53 |
| 4 | 12 | H | 1 | 1185488-79022 | 4/11/2023 18:51 |
| 5 | 8 | T | 1 | 11734672-61078 | 4/11/2023 18:48 |
| 6 | 8 | T | 1 | 14288106-4729 | 4/11/2023 18:40 |